# Stateful workflow engine vs Orchestrated idempotent services

Tags: microservices, activiti, camunda, business-process-management, saga

I realize the benefits of workflow engine such as easy to understand communication, easy waiting, parallelism and compensative actions with informative graphical model. The concept is great and more manageable than dogmatic event driven architecture without central coordinator and specified flow.

We are currently using legacy workflow engine to orchestrate microservices in insurance business. Over the time chunks of business logic and little helper scripts has creeped into process model, which is not developer friendly solution to maintain and test with continuous integration standards. Also the lack of available expertise and future support is a huge risk from the project management perspective.

I played around with Camunda and Activiti, but immediately faced compability issues with Spring Boot 3 and a lack of up to date examples and general knowledge outside of relatively small user community. This gives me a bad feeling of drowning into the same swamp as we are now in the future.

We planned design our own Java based orchestrator, which just invokes specified microservices in a specified order when the process is started or user task is completed. The orchestrator will also handle monitoring and versioning of the process flow. It's up to microservices to validate their business context and halt the process by raising user tasks if necessary. When user task is completed, the orchestrator restarts the whole process from the beginning with all tasks cleared. It is the responsibility of microservices to no-op when their work is already done in the previous run. Eventually, the process will reach it's end and finish. This solution would be a good balance of modern DX and coordinated process management.

Is there examples or name for such an idempotent orchestrated architecture?

Comment: `but immediately faced compability issues with Spring Boot 3` what exact compatibility issues you faced with Spring Boot? Camunda provides [native support](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/community-clients/spring/) of Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to build your own. Use [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project. Besides Java SDK it supports Go, Typescript/Javascript, Python, PHP.

The project started at Uber in 2016. There are hundreds of companies using it for mission critical applications.

Answer (score 2):

You only get into the challenge of aligning dependencies between your services and the process engine (and other components) if you tightly couple the orchestration / engine with the services. Happened to me many times in the past, too. If you separate the engine (called remote process engine with Camunda 7, only architecture with Camunda 8), then you are not influenced by its dependencies. Try for instance the Camunda RUN distribution and the [external task pattern](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/) or C8 SaaS to get to a cleaner, decoupled architecture. See Bernd Ruecker's reasoning [here](https://medium.com/berndruecker/moving-from-embedded-to-remote-workflow-engines-8472992cc371).

Details will depend on your specific requirements, but I would definitely advise anyone against building a homegrown solution. There are enough options in the market and these times are over. Requirements grow over time. There are security vulnerabilities to be aware of and to fix, etc. High maintenance, no market for resources, no synergies, you would need to maintain proprietary knowledge in the company and cannot achieve the same level of quality and feature richness as a more broadly used solution can. For a list of options see for instance [Bernd Ruecker's articles](https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/understanding-the-process-automation-landscape-9406fe019d93). Among the available options I would personally prefer an orchestrator, which uses a graphical process modelling approach based on the BPMN 2 standand. It helps clarity, knowledge transfer, and Business-IT alignment and the standard is a vendor-independent skill set.